# Set highlight color of selected text for NSTextField

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstextfield

Is it possible to set the highlight color of selected text for NSTextField objects? By default it takes the color the user has set in his system preferences, but I'd like to change it to a dark gray with white text to match the style of my application.